# Using jQuery to change a PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've in my view, an echo that displays a number after a PHP function :

```
<div id="delete_pref">
    <?php echo $iNbPrefSsrs; ?>
</div>
```

I would like to change this value using jQuery/AJAX (if it's possible). 
It can be hiding the old value / showing the new one, setting a new value or anything, I would like several ways if possible.

In my AJAX, i'm calling the same php function that counts this number when I visit the page or when I click on a button supposed to delete it.
 i've this :

```
$aRetourJson['number'] = $oControlePortail->count_config_to_delete();
```

I've my new value stored in the JS:

```
var iNewValue= aData['NewValue'];
```

And in the end in my javascript code, After the click, the ajax etc.

I would like to know what to with this :

```
$('#delete_pref').???
```

Comment: `$('#delete_pref').text(yourValue)` or `$('#delete_pref').html(yourValue)` should do the trick.

Comment: `$('#delete_pref').text(aData['NewValue']);`

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to use .val but I realised that val is not used in this case, this is for input or other specifics elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#delete_pref').html(iNewValue)` to replace old value with the new one received from server via `ajax`

Comment: After testing few things it seems that I've a problem with AJAX so i'll dig this way. I'll consider this problem as solved, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$('#delete_pref').html(iNewValue);
```

Source :
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery function `text()` if you want to assign text to an element :

```
$('#delete_pref').text(iNewValue);
```

But if you have HTML code you could assign it using `html()` :

```
$('#delete_pref').html(iNewValue);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

See demo: [DEMO Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu85g8rL/1/)
Use this:

```
$('div#delete_pref').html(iNewValue);
```

Comment: Reason for downvoting ?